# A map from the torus to the real line which is not a trivial fiber bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, fiber-bundles

I want to understand the map $\pi: \mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2\to \mathbb R$, by $(x,y)\mod \mathbb Z^2\mapsto y-\sqrt 2x $. Why it can not be a local trivial fiber bundle? Is $\pi$ surjective? If not, is $\pi( \mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2)$ a manifold?

Comment: Your map is not even a little bit well-defined.

Comment: I meant what I just edited. sorry

Comment: Again, it's still not well-defined. $(1,1)$ maps to $1 - \sqrt{2}$, but $(2,1)$ maps to $2 - \sqrt{2}$, and $(2,0)$ maps to $2$. All of these are in the same equivalence class but map to different numbers.

Comment: Thanks. But I am still looking for an example which is not locally trivial fiber bundle. Do you know some?

Comment: Since the torus is compact, a smooth map from the torus to $\mathbb R$ cannot be surjective. And since the only compact one-dimensional manifold is $S^1$, which does not embed into $\mathbb R$, the image cannot be a manifold either.